# Find a substring, replace a substring according the case

Tags: c#

What's the easiest and fastest way to find a sub-string(template) in a string and replace it with something else following the template's letter case (if all lower case - replace with lowercase, if all upper case  - replace with uppercase, if begins with uppercase and so on...)

so if the substring is in curly braces

```
"{template}" becomes "replaced content"
"{TEMPLATE}" becomes "REPLACED CONTENT" and
"{Template}" becomes "Replaced content" but
"{tEMPLATE}" becomes "rEPLACED CONTENT"
```

Comment: If not all characters are Lower/Upper - just skip substring occurence?

Comment: if template is set in "Camel case" fashion just determine the rest by examining first two letters... oh geee... I just realized - anytime it depends only on a pair of leading letters

Comment: Are these the only 4 cases? Or do you have more, for instance, `{tEmPlAte}`, and so forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing that:

```
public static string ReplaceWithTemplate(this string original, string pattern, string replacement)
{
  var template = Regex.Match(original, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value.Remove(0, 1);
  template = template.Remove(template.Length - 1);
  var chars = new List<char>();
  var isLetter = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < replacement.Length; i++)
  {
     if (i < (template.Length)) isLetter = Char.IsUpper(template[i]);
     chars.Add(Convert.ToChar(
                       isLetter ? Char.ToUpper(replacement[i]) 
                                : Char.ToLower(replacement[i])));
  }

  return new string(chars.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use regular expressions and a match evaluator callback like this:

```
regex = new Regex(@"\{(?<value>.*?)\}", 
    RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

string replacedText = regex.Replace(<text>, 
    new MatchEvaluator(this.EvaluateMatchCallback));
```

And your evaluator callback would do something like this:

```
private string EvaluateMatchCallback(Match match) {
    string templateInsert = match.Groups["value"].Value;
    // or whatever
    string replacedText = GetReplacementTextBasedOnTemplateValue(templateInsert);
    return replacedText;
}
```

Once you get the regex match value you can just do a case-sensitive comparison and return the correct replacement value.

**EDIT** I sort of assumed you were trying to find the placeholders in a block of text rather than worry about the casing per se, if your pattern is valid all the time then you can just check the first two characters of the placeholder itself and that will tell you the casing you need to use in the replacement expression:

```
string foo = "teMPLATE";
if (char.IsLower(foo[0])) {
    if (char.IsLower(foo[1])) {
        // first lower and second lower
    }
    else {
        // first lower and second upper
    }
}
else {
    if (char.IsLower(foo[1])) {
        // first upper and second lower
    }
    else {
      // first upper and second upper
    }
}
```

I would still use a regular expression to match the replacement placeholder, but that's just me.

Comment: -1. I consider this solution to be an overkill. What warrants the usage of regular expressions and callbacks - wouldn't a simple if statements and a.Replace method suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the case of the first two letters of the placeholder and choose one of the four case transforming strategies for the inserted text.

```
public static string Convert(string input, bool firstIsUpper, bool restIsUpper)
{
    string firstLetter = input.Substring(0, 1);
    firstLetter = firstIsUpper ? firstLetter.ToUpper() : firstLetter.ToLower();
    string rest = input.Substring(1);
    rest = restIsUpper ? rest.ToUpper() : rest.ToLower();
    return firstLetter + rest;
}

public static string Replace(string input, Dictionary<string, string> valueMap)
{
    var ms = Regex.Matches(input, "{(\\w+?)}");
    int i = 0;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < ms.Count; j++)
    {
        string pattern = ms[j].Groups[1].Value;
        string key = pattern.ToLower();
        bool firstIsUpper = char.IsUpper(pattern[0]);
        bool restIsUpper = char.IsUpper(pattern[1]);
        sb.Append(input.Substring(i, ms[j].Index - i));
        sb.Append(Convert(valueMap[key], firstIsUpper, restIsUpper));
        i = ms[j].Index + ms[j].Length;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

public static void DoStuff()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Replace("--- {aAA} --- {AAA} --- {Aaa}", new Dictionary<string,string> {{"aaa", "replacement"}}));
}
```

Comment: well, can you tell me how to wrap it in elegant code snippet?